# PCA evaluation with Shannon Entropy

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, entropy, information-theory

I'm working on a fairly large dataset (5e5 samples in a 22 dimensional space); I'm reducing the dimensionality of this dataset with PCA.
Since a lot of variables are cross-correlated, I group the variables that are highly correlated and then I collapse them in one variable by projecting them on thier first PC [1].
I want to evaluate how much information I lose in this process, so I evaluate the shannon entropy of the dataset before and after dimensionality reduction.
I estimate the Shannon entropy in the following way:

- I estimate the probability densitiy function of the dataset with KDE;
- I estimate the Shannon entropy as: $H = \sum_i pdf(x_i)\log({pdf(x_i)^{-1}})$;

For computational reasons, I use the first 1000 samples to estimate the entropy.
To my surprise, the entropy is higher in the reduced dataset; I'd expect to lose information in dimensionality reduction.
Is my code wrong, or the increase in entropy is due to the fact that -by looking at the first 1000 samples- I'm looking at a sort of "density of information" that increases because PCA better condensates information?

Below is my code:

- Imports:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math as m
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity as KDE
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
```

- Entropy estimation:

```py
def pdfKDE(X):
    kde = KDE(bandwidth=1,kernel='gaussian').fit(X)
    return kde.score_samples(X)

def H(X):
    pdf = pdfKDE(X)
    pdf = np.exp(pdf)
    h = 0.
    for p in pdf:
        h += p*m.log(p**-1)
    return h
```

- PCA aggregation of correlated variables:

```py
# corrMatrix is the Pearson's correlation factor matrix between variables
def pcaDatasetReduction(X,corrMatrix,treshold=0.9):
    dumpedVariables = []
    aggregatedVariables = []
    reducedDataset = []
    pca = PCA(n_components=1)

    # loop through each row
    for i in range(corrMatrix.shape[0]):
        # if the variable was already reduced, ignore
        if i in dumpedVariables:
            continue
        # loop through each column
        for j in range(i+1,corrMatrix.shape[0]):
            # if a variable is too highly correlated
            if corrMatrix[i,j] >= treshold:
                if j not in dumpedVariables:
                    dumpedVariables.append(j)
                    aggregatedVariables.append(j)

        # if some correlated variables are found
        # aggregate them
        if aggregatedVariables != []:
            dumpedVariables.append(i)
            aggregatedVariables = [i] + aggregatedVariables
            # extract correlated variables
            corrVar = X[:,aggregatedVariables]
            # Find PC
            pca.fit(corrVar)
            # Project variables on PC
            projVar = pca.transform(corrVar)
            # save reduced dataset
            reducedDataset.append(projVar)
            aggregatedVariables = []
        # else, if the variable was not merged, keep the variable in the dataset
        elif i not in dumpedVariables:
            reducedDataset.append(X[:,i].T)
        else:
            pass
        
        reducedDatasetNP = reducedDataset[0]
        for array in reducedDataset[1:]:
            reducedDatasetNP = np.column_stack((reducedDatasetNP,array))

    return reducedDatasetNP
```

[1] I used this strategy because some variables in my dataset are strongly correlated, while others are uncorrelated. So, instead of projecting all data on the first $p$ principal components, I decided to keep unmodified the variables that are uncorrelated to all of the others and to aggregate the correlated ones. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Your code is not a minimum working example because there are no library imports.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've fixed that. Thank you :)